# Are non-Muslims committing haram by not praying to Allah?

Tags: halal-haram, quran

Islam is a religion that encompasses a wide range of beliefs and practices. At the core of these beliefs is the concept of submission to the will of Allah. Muslims believe in the oneness of God and follow a set of religious practices that are considered obligatory.

In this context, it is interesting to consider the perspective on non-Muslims who do not pray to Allah. Are they considered to be committing haram according to Islamic law? If so, what are the implications of this for their standing in the eyes of Allah and their relationship with Muslims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Non-muslims are committing haram by not believing in Islam and by not practicing its constituents such as by not praying, and by not giving zakat etc. There are verses in the Quran which condemn them for it:

> ما سلككم في سقر قالوا لم نك من المصلين ولم نك نطعم المسكين وكنا نخوض مع الخائضين وكنا نكذب بيوم الدين
>
> "What has caused you to enter Hell?".  They will say: "We were not of those who used to offer the Salât (prayers). Nor did we used to feed the poor. And we used to enter into vain discourse with those who engaged [in it]. And we used to belie the Day of Recompense.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 74:42-46](https://quran.com/74/42-46?translations=203)</sup>

> وويل للمشركين الذين لا يؤتون الزكاة وهم بالآخرة هم كافرون
>
> And woe to those who associate others with Allah - Those who do not give zakah, and in the Hereafter they are disbelievers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 41:6-7](https://quran.com/41/6?translations=20)</sup>

> فلا صدق ولا صلى ولكن كذب وتولى
>
> And the disbeliever had not believed, nor had he prayed. But [instead], he denied and turned away
>
> <sup>— [Quran 75:31-32](https://quran.com/75/31-32?translations=20)</sup>

The implication in the eyes of Allah is that they are punished in this world, the grave, and in the hereafter they are in Hell. And the implication in relation to the Muslims is that they will be treated as kuffar in all matters of law - the details of which are too extensive to cover here.

Comment: I am hindu, will I get punished by Allah ?

Comment: Yes if you die without converting to Islam.

Comment: @UmH you say "that they are punished in this world": Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @AnkurSinha The verses are not to be taken too literally but allegorical. If one dies without knowing truth but had done it's best to reach , then Allah knows the best. But if one dies without following truth even if he were aware , due to personal or worldly reasons , he's meant to be punished. Nevertheless, Allah knows the best one's inside , not the muslims. We can't go and tell anyone that he'll go to hell or heaven.

Comment: @Jeschu There are numerous verses that talk of punishment\disgrace in this world e.g. 3:56, 13:34, 9:14